# Limit of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\sqrt{x-\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt[4]{x-\sqrt[5]{x-.....}}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I known how to find the limit of my last question which was [Finding $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x....}}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044984/finding-lim-x-rightarrow-1-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx), but I couldn't how to start to find the limit of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\sqrt{x-\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt[4]{x-\sqrt[5]{x-.....}}}}$$     so I used  a program written in visual basic 6 to calculate it.I found the limit about equal to $29/30$ but I am not sure if this value is right because the accuracy of this language not enough to give me a trust value. Anyhow,I want to know how to find the limit analytically.

Comment: If you try to calculate this with a program, the result depends on what initial value you have for the roots, if the initial value is $0$, the final result is $1$, if the initial value is $1$ the final result is $0$, if it's between $0$ and $1$ it converges to $0.581881$ and it fails otherwise. I'm guessing the actual answer is $0.581881$ but who knows.

Comment: I tried just evaluating it with $x=1$ and $100000$ nested roots. The initial value I was talking about is the value I assigned to the $1000001$ root since I cant evaluate all infinite roots.

Comment: However I get the same result with $x=1.0001$, with $x<1$ I get undefined and with $x=2$ I get $1$

Comment: Can you post the program you used to evaluate the limit?

Comment: That calculates $$\sqrt[100]{x-\sqrt[99]{x-\sqrt[98]{x-\cdots}}}$$ Also please use something like pastebin

Comment: This is the program that I used http://pastebin.com/7vJ3TYM7

Comment: I get $L=0.5818805230597856271212893881\ldots$

Comment: @Lucian I think the problem in my programming language.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not proved that a limit exists.

The figure below will give a new view on this question of limit or no limit. We consider an infinite set of functions $y_1(x)$ , $y_2(x)$ , ... , $y_n(x)$ , ... where the index $n$ is the number of radicals :

[image]

In case of the functions with odd index, the limit for $x$ tending to $1$ is  $y(1)=1$

In case of the functions with even index, the limit for $x$ tending to $1$ is  $y(1)=0$

When the number of radicals tends to infinity without specified parity, the limit is not defined. So we could say that there is no limit for the expression given in the wording of the question.

But, what is interresting is not the set of functions and corresponding curves, but what is the boundary curve of the infinite set of curves. This curve is not included into the set itself. The corresponding function might be on the form $y_{boundary}(x)=f(x)H(x-1)$ where H is the symbol of the Heaviside step function. Looking for $f(x)$ is something else: This is a challenge.

IN ADDITION :

We can express the firsts terms of the series expansion around $x=1$.

Let $x=1+\epsilon$ ,  with $\epsilon$ close to $0$.

$y_1=1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}+O(\epsilon^2)$

$y_2=(\frac{2\epsilon}{3})^{1/2}+O(\epsilon^{2/2})$

$y_3=1-(\frac{3\epsilon}{32})^{1/3}+O(\epsilon^{2 /3})$

$y_4=(\frac{4\epsilon}{405})^{1/8}+O(\epsilon^{2/8})$

$y_5=1-(\frac{5\epsilon}{201326592})^{1/15}+O(\epsilon^{2/15})$

$y_6=(\frac{2\epsilon}{ 10296910184203125})^{1/48}+O(\epsilon^{2/48})$

etc.

For $\epsilon=0$, this confirms that $y_n$  is alternatively equal to $0$ and to $1$ when $n$ tends to infinity.

When $n$ tends to infinity, the curves corresponding to the functions $y_n(x)$ tend asymptotically to a curve $f(x)$ for $x>1$. For $x=1$, $y_n(1)$ tends to $1$ if $n$ is odd, or tends to $0$ if $n$ is even.

The bounding curve corresponding to $f(x)$ is drawn in red on the figures below, represented in various enlargements. Of course, the curve in red is the same for all the figures. It looks like a straight line if we consider a range of $x$ close to $x=1$, but it is a misleading impression : $f(x)$ is not a linear function. The computation for drawing $f(x)$ was made with an algorithm similar to that given by Han de Bruijn.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the curves you have plotted there? I don't get the same result for $x<1$, the function is complex for odd index $>1$ there, and neither real nor imaginary part resembles what you've plotted. Looks like you've plotted something like $\sqrt x+f_i(x)$ for $x<1$ and $i>1$, $i$ odd.

Comment: $y_3$ is real if $x>1$ because $x>x^{1/3}>(x-x^{1/4})^{1/3}$ and $x>x^{1/4}$ if x>1. OTOH, if $x<1$ then $x-x^{1/4}<0$ so $x-(x-x^{1/4})^{1/3}>x$ and it has a real square-root, so $y_3$ is real again.

Comment: @Ruslan: The seven curves ploted on the figure correspond to the seven equations written on the same figure : $y_1(x)$ , $y_2(x)$ , ..., $y_7(x)$. Of course, they are ploted in real domains for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Michael oh, indeed. Was basing my comment on Mathematica plot. It appears to take the wrong branch of cubic root, funny!..

Comment: @Ruslan, if you raise a negative number to 0.33333, it has to multiply the angle $\pi$ by 0.33333  Is there an nth-root command in Mathematica?

Comment: @Michael yeah, there's a command, but it transforms internally to `Power[x,1/3]`, where although `1/3` is an exact number $\frac13$ (not an approximation like $0.33333$), the principal branch is defined differently from specifically `CubeRoot[]` or `Surd[]`. I.e. you can enter $\sqrt[3]x$ via `Ctrl+2`$\to$`x`$\to$`Ctrl+5`$\to$`3`, and it'll be taken as $x^{1/3}$. Using `Surd[]` fixes the problem, so the plots in this answer are actually correct.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer.** Please read the
[answer by JJacquelin](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045275/limit-of-lim-x-rightarrow-1-sqrtx-sqrt3x-sqrt4x-sqrt5x/1077945#1077945) . Without it, the answer you are reading now wouldn't even
come into existence - literally : *the possibility of no-limit must not be rejected*.
It must be admitted that the current answer rests upon the *assumption* that the limit does indeed exist.
But the question is: does it exist?

From a **computational point of view** , this question is related to :

- [Evaluating the sum $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[2]{2+\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt[4]{2+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{2}}}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837189/evaluating-the-sum-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt22-sqrt32-sqrt42-cdots-s/878189#878189) .

And via this reference it is related to at least three other questions.
The common denominator is that **backward recursion** may be employed here too.
For the problem at hand, this backward recursion goes as follows: 
$$
a_{k-1} = \sqrt[k]{x - a_k} = e^{\ln(x - a_k)/k} \qquad ( x-a_k > 0 )
$$
Starting "from infinity" with $\,x=1\,$ (where $\,\infty = 100\,$ is large enough for our purpose) , but with *arbitrary* $\;0 < a_\infty < 1$ , the recursion invariably leads to the outcome in the comment by Lucian and Kristoffer Ryhl :
$$
L = 0.5818805230597856271212893881
$$ 
Here is the Pascal program snippet that does the job:

```
program Lucian;

procedure test;
const
  n : integer = 100; { = oo }
var
  k : integer;
  a,x,d : double;
begin
  while true do
  begin
    a := Random;
    x := 1; d := 1;
  { Backward recursion }
    for k := n downto 2 do 
    begin
      a := exp(ln(x-a)/k);
    { Error analysis }
      d := d*a/(x-a)/k;
    end;
    Writeln(a,' +/-',d);
    Readln;
  end;
end;

begin
  test;
end.
```

Output:

```
 5.81880523059786E-0001 +/- 2.39470132977704E-0043
 5.81880523059786E-0001 +/- 6.60618483531661E-0045
 5.81880523059786E-0001 +/- 4.15120583976206E-0044
```

The generality of $\;0 < a_\infty < 1$ sounds more impressive than it is.
Because, apart from the first one, the iterations actually start with numbers
close to and somewhat smaller than $1$  ($0 < x-a_n < 1$) :
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x - a_n} = 1
$$
An estimate for the errors may be obtained by differentiation:
$$
d a_{k-1} = d \sqrt[k]{x-a_k} = d a_k \frac{1}{k} \left(x-a_k\right)^{1/k-1}
= \frac{a_{k-1}}{k(x-a_k)}d a_k
$$
starting with $\,da_k = 1\,$ for some sufficiently large value $n$
of $k$ , in our case $\,n=100$ . It is observed that the error in $\;a_1\;$ can be
calculated (more or less) by backward recursion as well.  It may well be
conjectured that some reasonable bound goes like $\,1/n!$ ,
meaning that convergence is rather fast. Apart from the first iterations, though,
where there are large denominators, due to the fact that $a_{\infty-1}$ is close
to $x=1$ .

**Notes.**
If we change `x := 1` in the program by a slightly different value *below* $1$ ,
say `x := 0.99` , then the iterations quickly become *unstable* for some $\;a_\infty$ , even if reasonable precautions are taken.
So it seems that the limit should better be approached from above : $\;x \downarrow 1$ in the first place.

Furthermore, <quote>
it is supposed that $a\ne 0$ and $a\ne 1$ . This is a not proved assumption.
Doing this is something like using the result
to be proved, to prove it. If $\,a=1\,$ or $\,a=0\,$ is the starting value for the recursion (case $\,x=1$ ), the result will be $\,0\,$ or $\,1\,$
(depending on the parity of $\,n\,$ in the program).</quote>

*Killing the fly in the soup ?*  
It's the difference between a closed interval $\,0 \le a \le 1\,$
and an open interval $\,0 < a < 1$ . I know it's a distortion
of the original problem, but my proposal would be to replace all
radicals $\,\sqrt[n]{a}\,$ by exponents $\,\exp(\ln(a)/n)$ , like
I've done in the program ( thus simply obviating the special cases
$a \in \{0,1\}$ ) . Wonder if that's acceptable for the OP.

BONUS. Making a graph of the following more general function $f(x)$ might be interesting. 
$$
f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[2]{x-\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt[4]{x-\cdots-\sqrt[n]{x}}}}
$$ 
So here goes, for $\;1 < x < 10\;$ and $\;0 < y < 5\;$ :

[image]

It is conjectured that $f(2) = 1$ . Proof :
Start with $a_n = 1$ , then
$\,a_{n-1} = \sqrt[n]{2 - 1} = 1$ and so on for all $\,a_k\,$ until $\,a_1$ .

Comment: The limit $L=0.581880523..$ obtained with this method of computation or other numerical method is the numerical approximation of $f(1)$ according to the definition of the function $f(x)$ in my answer. The equation of the bounding function is $f(x)H(x-1)$ where H is the Heaviside's step function. Of course, $f(x)$ has a limit for $x$ tending to $1$. But it is not a limit for the infinite nested radicals function which should be called an improper "limit" because it is an asymptotic limit to the step function $f(1)H(x-1)$ for $x$ tending to $1$.

Comment: @JJacquelin: my current interpretation (subject to change) is that you are using _forward recursion_, which is known to be (numerically) _unstable_. But  I do not deny beforehand that there may be a can of worms here.

Comment: @JJacquelin: I've updated my answer. Which doesn't mean that I don't listen, but I cannot pinpoint exactly where my reasoning could possibly go wrong. Is it perhaps in the denominators of the error estimates?

Comment: I think that your reasoning is correct, depending of what we are looking for. Your computer program is well adapted to the numerical computation of the so called $f(x)$ function : instead of starting with $x=1$ which leads to a good approximate of $f(1)$, we could start with other values of $x$ and draw the curve representing $f(x)$. So, your approach is in agreement with what I consider as the most interesting challenge: is there a closed form for this function ? . On the other hand, ... to be continued...

Comment: On the other hand, if we consider the question of the limit or no-limit of the infinite nested radicals function, by using the backward recursion, there is a fly in the soupe. The program starts with random values $0<a<1$. So it is supposed that $a\neq 0$ and $a\neq 1$. This is a not proved assumption. Doing this is something like using the result to be proved, to prove it. If $a=1$ or $a=0$ is the starting value for the recursion (case $x=1$), the result will be $0$ or $1$ (depending of the parity of $n$ in the program). This proves that the possibility of no-limit must not be rejected.

Comment: Han de Bruijn wrote: <<So it seems that the limit should better be approached from above >>. I think that your algorithm is perfectly convenient with any $0<a<1$ and preferably with $a$ not too close to $0$ or $1$ if the goal is to find the limit $f(1)$. As you can observe, if $a$ is too close to $1$ or $0$, the deviations are increassing and stability decreassing. On pure theoritical viewpoint, we know what append for $a=0$ and $a=1$: the limit is $0$ or $1$ depending on the parity of $n$.

Comment: I suggest to compare the results obtained with a given value of $a$, but in cases of $n=99$ and $n=100$ for example. The difference will probably be negligible if $a$ is not close to $0$ or $1$. Probably a large discrepancy will occur if $a$ is very close to $0$ or $1$ because the theoretical limits are not the same: $0$ in a case, $1$ in the other case.