# Evaluation of $\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\sqrt{\frac18+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^n}}}}}$

Tags: radicals

I was just playing around with a calculator, and came to the conclusion that:

$$\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\sqrt{\frac18+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^n}}}}} \approx 1.29$$

Now I'm curious. Is it possible to evaluate the exact value of the following?

Comment: In general, expressions like this that are easy to evaluate usually have some sort of symmetry such that we can relate the value to its self via e.g. a square like for example $x^2 = ax + b$. One such example is $x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2^2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2^4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{2^n}}}}$ since then $x^2 = \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2}x \to x = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$. This one does not have such a symmetry - which does not rule out an analytic solution, but it makes less likely / much harder to find it if it exist.

Comment: Well, proving convergence is at least not too difficult.

Comment: $1.2857367633569968672336\ldots$ does not possess a known closed form.

Comment: The two-letter answer "No" is not allowed.  Had it been allowed, it would have got the bounty!

Comment: How are people numerically evaluating this? It seems like it also suffers from some bad cancellation when using the obvious way (for loop from n = big to n = 0).

Answer (score 5):

This question is related to at least five others:

- [Problem 6 - IMO 1985](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759599/problem-6-imo-1985)
- [How to find this limit: $A=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576110/how-to-find-this-limit-a-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt1-sqrt-frac12-sqrt-fr)
- [Find the limit $L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}}}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582196/find-the-limit-l-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-frac12-sqrt3-frac13-cdo)
- [Evaluating the sum $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[2]{2+\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt[4]{2+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{2}}}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837189/evaluating-the-sum-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt22-sqrt32-sqrt42-cdots-s)
- [Limit of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\sqrt{x-\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt[4]{x-\sqrt[5]{x-…}}}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045275/limit-of-lim-x-rightarrow-1-sqrtx-sqrt3x-sqrt4x-sqrt5x)

This makes a short answer possible (and desirable).
For a *numerical* calculation *backward recursion* is proposed (again):
$$
  a_{n-1} = \sqrt{1/2^n+a_n} \qquad \mbox{with} \quad \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0
$$
Here comes the Pascal program snippet that is supposed to do the job:

```
program apart;

procedure again(n : integer);
var
  a,two : double;
  k : integer;
begin
  two := 1;
  for k := n downto 2 do
    two := two/2;
  a := 0;
  for k := n downto 2 do
  begin
    a := sqrt(two+a);
    two := two*2;
  end;
  Writeln(a);
end;

begin
  again(52);
end.
```

Note that an error analysis is not implemented in the program. This has not much sense
because the accuracy is determined by the smallest $1/2^n$ that can be represented
with some significance; that is for $n\approx 52$ in double precision Pascal.
The outcome is, of course, in concordance with the value already found by
Lucian:

```
 1.28573676335699E+0000
```

**Disclaimer.** I certainly would have tried the *closed form*
- whatever that means in modern times - if I only could believe that such
a thing does indeed exist here.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to show, assuming the limit exists:

$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+...}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$$

It is also easy to see the following set of inequalities:

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+1} < \sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\sqrt{\frac18+\cdots}}}<\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+...}}}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+1}} < \sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\sqrt{\frac18+\cdots}}}<\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+...}}}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}+1}}} < \sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\sqrt{\frac18+\cdots}}}<\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}+...}}}}$$

And so on, getting better and better approximations.

Calculating the nested radicals:

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+...}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+...}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}+...}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1.5}}{2}$$

We get following set of boundaries for the value we need:

$$R=\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\sqrt{\frac18+\cdots}}}=1.285737\dots$$

$$1.22474<R<1.36603$$

$$1.27202<R<1.30656$$

$$1.28251<R<1.29120$$

And so on. There is no closed form, but it's not hard to evaluate this nested radical with good precision.

Answer (score -6):

$$y=\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\sqrt{\frac18+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^n}}}}}\equiv\sqrt{\frac12+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac12+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}}\right)}$$

$$y=\sqrt{\frac12+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac12+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}}\right)}$$ But the Let the term in bracket be x
therefore:$$x=\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac12+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}}\equiv\sqrt{\frac12+x}$$ 
squaring both sides
$$x^2=\frac12+x$$ 
$$x^2-x-\frac12=0$$solving the equation gives:
$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
but we have $$y=\sqrt{\frac12+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac12+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}}\right)}=\sqrt{\frac12+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x}$$
Putting the value of x into y gives$$y=\sqrt{\frac12+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}}=1.211$$
Therefore $$\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\sqrt{\frac18+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^n}}}}}=1.211$$
This is an exact value.

Comment: @Adriandmen I just posted a solution for $\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\sqrt{\frac18+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^n}}}}}$

Comment: Please note that 
$$ \sqrt{\frac 1 2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}*\sqrt{\frac 1 2+\sqrt{\frac 1 4+\sqrt{...}}}} = \sqrt{\frac 1 2 + \sqrt{\frac 1 4+\frac 1 2\sqrt{\frac 1 4+\sqrt{...}}}} \neq \sqrt{\frac 1 2 + \sqrt{\frac 1 4+\sqrt{\frac 1 8+\sqrt{...}}}}$$

Comment: I see the mistake. thanks

Comment: will correct it now

Comment: @cirpis, I have corrected it

Comment: @Adriandmen, I have corrected it

Comment: @Winther check my solution for $$\sqrt{\frac12+\sqrt{\frac14+\sqrt{\frac18+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^n}}}}}$$

Comment: @sholaOtitoju Note that $\sqrt{1/2 + \sqrt{1/4+\sqrt{1/8+\sqrt{1/16+\ldots}}}} = \sqrt{1/2 + 1/\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1/2 + \sqrt{1/2+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{8+\ldots}}}}}$ so your formula is not correct. This is also easily checked numerically as the solution is $x = 1.2857\ldots$ while you get $x= 1.211\ldots$.